# Grouping Child Elements within Grouped Parent Elements XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, grouping

I am working on combining XML elements using `for-each-group` and the problem I am having is that these XML elements have children elements that have children of their own.
I would also like to combine the children elements as well.

My input XML looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
   </Header>
   <Summary ID="1">
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>340.00</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <DATA_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>340.00</_Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_2>
   </Summary>
   <Summary ID="1">
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Batch_Number>04002</Batch_Number>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>130.00</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <DATA_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>130.00</Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_2>
      <DATA_From_8>
         <Invoice_Amount>20</Invoice_Amount>
         <Invoice_Number>123</Invoice_Number>
      </DATA_From_8>
      <DATA_From_8>
         <Invoice_Amount>15</Invoice_Amount>
         <Invoice_Number>456</Invoice_Number>
      </DATA_From_8>
   </Summary>
   <Summary ID="2">
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>40.00</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <DATA_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>40.00</Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_2>
   </Summary>
   <Summary ID="2">
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>819.91</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <DATA_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>734.91</Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_2>
      <DATA_From_5>
         <Sales_Amount>85.00</Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_5>
   </Summary>
</Root>
```

Here is my XSLT file. I get close to my desired output, but instead of combining the same children elements, it puts all of them inside the `Summary` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Root>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/Root/Summary" group-by="@ID">
                    <Summary ID="{@ID}">
                        <!-- Copy values that are the same -->
                        <xsl:sequence select="ID, Batch_Date"/>

                        <!-- Sum the amounts -->
                        <Net_Sales_Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Net_Sales_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                        </Net_Sales_Amount>

                        <!-- Combine the record types in this Summary element -->
<!--                        <xsl:sequence select="DATA_From_2, DATA_From_3, DATA_From_5, DATA_From_8"/> -->

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="DATA_From_2">
                            <Data_From_2>
                                <Sales_Amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Data_From_2/Combined_Sales_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                                </Sales_Amount>
                            </Data_From_2>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="DATA_From_8">
                            <Data_From_8>
                                <Invoice_Amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Data_From_8/Invoice_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                                </Invoice_Amount>
                                <Invoice_Number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/Data_From_8/Invoice_Number" separator=" | "/>
                                </Invoice_Number>
                            </Data_From_8>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </Summary>
                </xsl:for-each-group>

                <Header>
                </Header>
                <Footer>
                </Footer>
            </Root>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my current output:

```
<Root>
   <Summary ID="1">
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>470.00</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>0.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>0.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <Data_From_8>
         <Invoice_Amount>0.00</Invoice_Amount>
         <Invoice_Number/>
      </Data_From_8>
      <Data_From_8>
         <Invoice_Amount>0.00</Invoice_Amount>
         <Invoice_Number/>
      </Data_From_8>
   </Summary>
   <Summary ID="2">
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>859.91</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>0.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>0.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>0.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
   </Summary>
</Root>
```

The XSLT is not combining the Data_From elements that are the same, and it's also not populating the values correctly.

This is what it should look like:

```
<Root>
   <Summary ID="1">
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>470.00</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>470.00</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <Data_From_8>
         <Invoice_Amount>35.00</Invoice_Amount>
         <Invoice_Number/>
      </Data_From_8>
   </Summary>
   <Summary ID="2">
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Batch_Date>0228</Batch_Date>
      <Net_Sales_Amount>859.91</Net_Sales_Amount>
      <Data_From_2>
         <Sales_Amount>771.91</Sales_Amount>
      </Data_From_2>
      <DATA_From_5>
         <Sales_Amount>85.00</Sales_Amount>
      </DATA_From_5>
   </Summary>
</Root>
```

The XSLT should combine the similar elements (Data_from_2, Data_from_5, etc) and add up the values.
I apologize for any typos or incorrect XML, I did a lot of copy and paste.
Thanks

Comment: how come `<Summary Merchant_ID="{@Merchant_ID}">` produce `<Summary ID="1">`

Comment: @vels4j - That was a copy paste error. I went through and tried making names simple and easy to understand. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following is what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Root>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/Root/Summary" group-by="@ID">
                    <Summary Merchant_ID="{@ID}">
                        <!-- Copy values that are the same -->
                        <xsl:sequence select="ID, Batch_Date"/>

                        <!-- Sum the amounts -->
                        <Net_Sales_Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Net_Sales_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                        </Net_Sales_Amount>

                        <!-- Combine the record types in this Summary element -->
<!--                        <xsl:sequence select="DATA_From_2, DATA_From_3, DATA_From_5, DATA_From_8"/> -->

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'DATA_')]" group-by="node-name(.)">
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                         </xsl:for-each-group>

                    </Summary>
                </xsl:for-each-group>

                <Header>
                </Header>
                <Footer>
                </Footer>
            </Root>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA_From_2 | DATA_From_5">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <Sales_Amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Sales_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                                </Sales_Amount>
                            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA_From_8">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <Invoice_Amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Invoice_Amount), '0.00')"/>
                                </Invoice_Amount>
                                <Invoice_Number>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/Invoice_Number" separator=" | "/>
                                </Invoice_Number>
                            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Its great writing `<Invoice_Number>123 | 456</Invoice_Number>`